# Passing MongoDB user password in newline for Mongodump command using bash script

Tags: mongodb, bash, mongodump

I am trying to backup a MongoDB instance that has authentication enabled but i get this error:

```
$> mongodump --username=admin --password=******* --authenticationDatabase=admin --db=ixpay --collection=blacklist --out=.

2020-06-02T21:39:39.086+0000    Failed: can't create session: could not connect to server: connection() : auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-256": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.
```

I am attempting this data dump using a bash script but i noticed that if i run the command directly on my terminal without the `--password` flag it works but then Mongodump shell will prompt for password like so:

```
$ mongodump --username=admin  --authenticationDatabase=admin --db=ixpay --collection=blacklist --out=.
Enter password:
```

How do i write the mongodump command in bash, so that i can interactively(but quietly) pass the password to the Mongodump command when i execute the script?

Comment: What do you mean by interactively(but quietly)?  Running mongodump from the script without the password argument should let you interactively provide the password.

Comment: Is there a special character in your password which the shell is swallowing? Try putting your password in quotes?

Comment: @JoeDrumgoole, yes you were right i cross-checked the password and realized that it had $ in it. Thanks for pointing that out. Adding it to a quote i was able to pass the --password and --username flag to the mongodump command.